# Almost sure convergence of nonrandom sample

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, means

This is a question about almost sure convergence. Consider the following set-up:

1. There are $B$ banks. Each has size $S_{b}$, which follows a size distribution $f_{S}$ with mean E[S]. $f_{S}$ is positively skewed (but with finite variance).
2. The probability that firm $f$ borrows from bank $b$ follows a Bernoulli distribution:
   $P(a_{b}=1)=p_{b}=\frac{\tilde{S}_{b}}{Z}B^{-\zeta}$.
   Where:

   $B$ is the number of banks.

   $\tilde{S}_{b}$ is the size of bank $b$ to the average bank size:    $\frac{S_{b}}{E[S]}$.

   $Z$ is a scaling parameter.

   $\zeta \in (0,1)$.

This set-up implies that, everything else equal, larger banks lend to more firms (compared to smaller banks).

The question is about to what the following converges:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sum_{b=1}^{B}a_{b}(B)}\sum_{b=1}^{B}a_{b}(B)S_{b}\xrightarrow{a.s.}
\end{equation}

It will not be the population mean E[S], because our sampling procedure tends to have larger banks in the sample.

Thanks

Comment: The notation here is confusing.  The main problem is in your limit equation, the right-hand-side seems to depend on an index $b$, while the left-hand-side does not.  It also seems there is no reason to include an index for the firm $f$, the existence of different firms plays no role in your summation.  Also, the summation $\sum_{b=1}^B a_{fb}B_b$ should be represented $\sum_{b=1}^B a_b(B) S_b$, where $S_b$ is the size of bank $b$ and $a_b(B)$ is the coefficient (which changes depending on the number of banks $B$, as opposed to  $a_{fb}$ that suggests no dependence on the number of banks $B$).

Comment: I also assume that the limit is with respect to the number of banks $B$ going to infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have adapted the notation, which should be no longer confusing. The limit is indeed w.r.t. the number of banks.

Answer (score 0):

Sampling based on bank size skews the sampled mean.  Here is a simplified setting that shows what tends to happen:

Let $\{S_1, S_2, S_3, \ldots \}$ be i.i.d. bank sizes with finite mean $E[S]$.   Let $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots\}$ be a sequence of Bernoulli variables where $a_b$ depends only on $S_b$.  Assume $Pr[a_b=1|S_b]=g(S_b)$ for some given function $g(s) \in [0,1]$ (an example is $g(s) = s/S_{max}$, assuming $S_b \in [0, S_{max}]$ for some given maximum value $S_{max}$, which says the probability of sampling depends on the bank size). Then $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots\}$ is an i.i.d. sequence, also $\{a_1S_1, a_2S_2, a_3S_3, \ldots\}$ is an i.i.d. sequence, and by the law of large numbers we have (with prob 1):

$$ \lim_{B\rightarrow\infty} \left[\frac{\sum_{b=1}^Ba_bS_b}{\sum_{b=1}^Ba_b}\right] = \lim_{B\rightarrow\infty} \left[\frac{\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^Ba_bS_b}{\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^Ba_b}\right] = \frac{E[a_1S_1]}{E[a_1]}$$

We get $E[a_1S_1]/E[a_1] = E[S_1]$ only if $a_1$ and $S_1$ are uncorrelated, which is typically *not* the case.  If $a_1$ and $S_1$ are positively correlated then $E[a_1S_1]/E[a_1] > E[S_1]$, which is intuitive since it means we tend to sample when the bank size is larger than the mean.

If $g(s) = s/S_{max}$ for $s \in [0, S_{max}]$ then: 
$$ \frac{E[a_1S_1]}{E[a_1]} = \frac{E[S_1^2]}{E[S_1]} = E[S_1] + \frac{Var(S_1)}{E[S_1]}$$

---

Your question setting is more complicated because the $a_b(B)$ coefficients depend on $B$, and the standard LLN cannot be used. Assume $\{S_1, S_2, ...\}$ is an iid sequence with mean $E[S]$ and with $S_b \in [0, S_{max}]$ for some finite max size $S_{max}$.  For each given $B$, define $\{a_1(B), a_2(B), ..., a_B(B)\}$ as Bernoulli variables where $a_b(B)$ depends only on $S_b$, and has: 
$$ Pr[a_b(B)=1|S_b] = \frac{S_bB^{-\xi}}{ZE[S]} $$
This is a valid probability whenever the constant $Z$ satisfies $ZE[S] \geq S_{max}$.  Notice that: 
$$ E[a_b(B)] = E[E[a_b(B)|S_b]] = \frac{B^{-\xi}}{Z} $$
Define scaled values $\tilde{a}_b(B) = ZB^{\xi}a_b(B)$.  Thus, $E[\tilde{a}_b(B)]=1$. Then: 
$$ \frac{\sum_{b=1}^Ba_b(B)S_b}{\sum_{b=1}^Ba_b(B)} = \frac{\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)S_b}{\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)} = \frac{\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)S_b}{\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)} $$
You want to show that, with prob 1: 
\begin{align}
&\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)=1\\
&\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)S_b= \frac{E[S^2]}{E[S]} 
\end{align}
Notice that no relationship between $a_1(B)$ and $a_1(B+1)$ has been defined, yet, the Borell-Cantelli lemma is a way to proceed even without this definition (see below).

For preliminary intuition, notice that the means of the numerator and denominator coincide with the conjectured limiting values: 
\begin{align}
&E\left[\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)\right] = 1\\
&E\left[\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B)S_b\right] = \frac{E[S^2]}{E[S]}
\end{align}

---

For the first limit: Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Then for each $B$: 
\begin{align}Pr\left[\left|\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B (\tilde{a}_b(B)-1)\right|>\epsilon\right] &\leq \frac{E\left[ \left(\sum_{b=1}^B (\tilde{a}_b(B)-1)\right)^4 \right]}{\epsilon^4B^4} \\
&= \frac{BE[(\tilde{a}_1(B)-1)^4] + 3B(B-1)E[(\tilde{a}_1(B)-1)^2]^2}{\epsilon^4 B^4}\\
&\leq \frac{BO(B^{3\xi}) + O(B^2)O(B^{2\xi})}{\epsilon^4B^4} \\
& \leq \frac{O(1)}{\epsilon^4 B^{2(1-\xi)}}
\end{align}
If $\xi \in [0,1/2)$ then $2(1-\xi) > 1$ and $\sum_{B=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{B^{2(1-\xi)}} < \infty$, so Borel-Cantelli implies (with prob 1, and assuming $\xi \in [0, 1/2)$): 
$$ \lim_{B\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^B\tilde{a}_b(B) = 1 $$
Now, it might be the case that we also get convergence for $\xi \in [1/2, 1)$ (I don't know),  but then $\sum_{B=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{B^{2(1-\xi)}} = \infty$ and the above proof fails.  We need another way to prove, I also suspect you would need to specify the relationship between $a_1(B)$ and $a_1(B+1)$ if you want to explore $\xi \in [1/2, 1)$. The standard LLN proof of using finite variance and nonnegativity does not seem to work here since the coefficients $a_b(B)$ are doubly indexed.

Comment: The question asked is more complex because $a_b(B)$ changes with $B$, and its probability decreases to 0. I believe that if $S_b \in [0, S_{max}]$ for all $b$ (for some finite $S_{max}$), and if $\xi \in [0, 1/2)$ then we get (with prob 1): $$ \lim_{B\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sum_{b=1}^B a_b(B)S_b}{\sum_{b=1}^Ba_b(B)} = \frac{E[S^2]}{E[S]}$$ The idea is to repeat the standard proof of the law of large numbers with finite fourth moment, I think $\xi \in [0, 1/2)$ is sufficient to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma here.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Michael, it has made things clearer for me, but the issue is still not completely resolved. First of all, $S_{b} \in [0,\infty]$. E.g. $S_{b}$ could be a lognormal distribution. Second, I do not now why the fact that $a_{b}(B)$ goes to zero is an issue. Suppose all banks had an equal chance of being included in the sample: $p_{b}=\frac{1}{B}$. In that case, it would be a random sample and the expression would converge to $E[S]$. In that case, $\frac{1}{B}$ would converge to zero as well and does not require the Borel-Cantelli lemma. Thank you.

Comment: On your first point, I made $S_b \in [0, S_{max}]$ for quite practical reasons:  Then it makes sense to define $Pr[a_b=1|S_b] = \frac{S_bB^{-\xi}}{ZE[S]}$ as a probability whenever $ZE[S] \geq S_{max}$. If $S_b$ could get arbitrarily large, then $Pr[a_b=1|S_b]$ can be greater than 1!  Thus, I think there are some problems in your model.

Comment: On your second point: I have no idea what you are trying to say.  The problem is that if you make $Pr[a_b=1|S_b, B]$ a function of $B$, then you are not allowed to reuse the same  $a_b$ values.  Every time you get a new $B$, you need to get new $a_b$ values. So, this is not the standard law of large numbers (LLN).  Standard LLN has an i.i.d. sequence $\{X_1, X_2, ...\}$ and says $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=E[X]$ with prob 1.

Comment: In contrast to standard LLN, you seem to have a _doubly indexed_ sequence $\{X_1(B), X_2(B), ..., X_B(B)\}_{B=1}^{\infty}$ and you ask when $\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{B}\sum_{i=1}^BX_i(B) = E[X]$.  Notice that you also have not specified the relationship between $X_1(B)$ and $X_1(B+1)$ (are they independent?)  (For example, is $a_1(B)$ independent of $a_1(B+1)$?) My comment above that uses Borell-Cantelli holds regardless of this relationship, it only assumes the $\{X_i(B)\}$ are i.i.d. over $i \in \{1, \ldots, B\}$ for each fixed $B$.

Comment: I added another part to my answer that gives the first part of the more complicated proof.